# ImageMagick "Channel distortion: Undefined" message

Tags: windows, imagemagick, distortion

I installed imagemagick for Windows from [official site](https://imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.8-57-Q16-x64-dll.exe). I am trying to generate a diff image from two PNG images using ImageMagick. I am using following command:

```
compare file2.png file1.png -compose Src "diff.png"
```

But command exits with EXIT code "1". When run with -verbose flag, below message gets printed.

> Image:file2.png  Channel distortion: Undefined

I searched google for possible reason, but haven't found any answer. There is official ImageMagick documentation on distortion, but that is too wide and technical (and I am a novice).

**Any idea why this message is thrown by imagemagick utility?**

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick? Did you install the 64-bit version or the 32-bit version and was it compatible with your computer? Your command works fine for me on IM 6.9.10.56 Q16 Mac OSX. If on IM 7, the use `magick compare` not simply `compare`. Is libpng installed as a delegate in your ImageMagick version? If on IM 6, what does `convert.exe -version` show. If on M 7, what does `magick.exe -verison` show. Note that Windows has its own convert.exe. So you may have to rename the IM convert.exe if on IM 6.

Comment: I used the latest installer. Not sure if i can answer any of your question but surely it was just false error coz when i see the folder diff png is present with expected content.

Comment: See my answer below. There is no real issue except you should specify a -metric XXX to get statistics returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real error. That message comes up when you do not specify -metric XXX with compare and take the default. The exit code 1 is what ImageMagick produces on success, I believe. See if you have an output file called diff.png. If you add -metric rmse, for example, you should not get that message. If I run the following without -metric XXX, I get:

```
compare -verbose lena.png lena.jpg -compose src diff.png

lena.png PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 118327B 0.010u 0:00.004
lena.jpg JPEG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 31640B 0.000u 0:00.002
Image: lena.png
  Channel distortion: Undefined
lena.png=>diff.png PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3c 1322B 0.130u 0:00.039
```

[image]

So it works fine. **The message is telling you that it does not know which metric to use to give you difference statistics.** I am not sure what it uses to generate the output. The term distortion may be a poor choice and perhaps should have been difference statistics.

If I add -metric rmse, then I get:

```
compare -verbose -metric rmse lena.png lena.jpg -compose src diff.png

lena.png PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 118327B 0.010u 0:00.004
lena.jpg JPEG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 31640B 0.000u 0:00.001
Image: lena.png
  Channel distortion: RMSE
    red: 810.821 (0.0123723)
    green: 658.701 (0.0100511)
    blue: 945.653 (0.0144297)
    all: 813.547 (0.0124139)
```

[image]

Similar or same resulting image, **but now the compare scores are reported since a specific metric is specified.**

See the section about comparison statistics [here](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This is what exactly happening. The diff file is already there. I think this is a false error.

Comment: Not a false error. It is just a warning telling you that no metric was supplied, so it could not generate statistics.